# Binary Search Tree insertion doesn't work

Tags: c, binary-tree, insertion

I am following  a book ,Problem Solving & Program Design in C, to learn C. In this book, they gave all necessary parts to build a binary search tree....
But, My implementation didn't work. Here is insertion part;

```
void
add_to_t(tree_node_t *oldTreep, // input/output - binary search tree
        tree_element_t ele)       // input - element to add
{
    oldTreep = tree_insert(oldTreep, ele);
}
tree_node_t * tree_insert(tree_node_t *oldTreep, tree_element_t ele)
{
    if(oldTreep == NULL){
        oldTreep = TYPED_ALLOC(tree_node_t);
        strcpy(oldTreep->element.name, ele.name);
        strcpy(oldTreep->element.sName, ele.sName);
        oldTreep->element.seatClass = ele.seatClass;
        oldTreep->leftp = NULL;
        oldTreep->rightp = NULL;
    }
    else if (strcmp(oldTreep->element.name, ele.name)==0){
        /* duplicate key - no insertion */
    }
    else if (strcmp(oldTreep->element.name, ele.name)>0){
        oldTreep->rightp = tree_insert(oldTreep->rightp, ele);
    }
    else
    {
        oldTreep->leftp = tree_insert(oldTreep->leftp, ele);
    }
    return(oldTreep);

}
```

My scan_passenger funvtion(I am passing ele from result of this function call);

```
void scan_passenger(tree_element_t *pass)
{
    char passName[10], passSname[10];
    int classNum;
    printf("\nEnter the Name of passenger to add the binary search tree> ");
    scanf("%s", passName);
    printf("Enter the Surname of passenger to add the binary search tree> ");
    scanf("%s", passSname);
    printf("Enter the class number of passenger to add the binary search tree> ");
    scanf("%d", &classNum);
    strcpy(pass->name, passName);
    strcpy(pass->sName, passSname);
    pass->seatClass = classNum;
}
```

And my typdefs and headers if needs;

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "string.h"
#define TYPED_ALLOC(type) (type *)malloc(sizeof (type))
typedef struct tree_element_s {
    char name[10];
    char sName[10];
    int seatClass;
}tree_element_t;

typedef struct tree_node_s {
    tree_element_t element;
    struct tree_node_s *leftp, *rightp;
}tree_node_t;
```

My problem is that it doesn't create a root of binary search tree. When I try to add a new element to heap, it seems, it creates a new node. When I traced my code, it seems every instance of this functions returns NULL. I am trying to say every time when I call tree_insert, it goes first if statement(Thinks root is NULL)...
Sorry for my bad English. And I may made some mistake when talking about coding terminology(it may because, I returned to study C from that book after absence of 1 year.So I may mixed them)
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In add_to_t, you update oldTreep, but since it is a local variable, the new value gets lost as soon as you leave the function.

You could, e.g., return the new value of oldTreep to the caller, which updates *his* oldTreep with the return value

```
tree_node_t
add_to_t(tree_node_t *oldTreep, // input/output - binary search tree 
        tree_element_t ele)       // input - element to add 
{ 
    return tree_insert(oldTreep, ele); 
} 

...

myRootOfTheTree = add_to_t (myRootOfTheTree, element);
```

Another solution is to always have one dummy element in the tree.